# fopen not able to open a writable file when using nvcc

Tags: gcc, cuda, fopen, nvcc

EDIT:  I believe the issue is due to nvcc invoking a C++ compiler instead of a C compiler because of an error I receive when I don't cast the malloc(3) call to a char*.  I am led to this assertion by: [Invalid converstion from void* to char**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185452/invalid-converstion-from-void-to-char)

EDITEDIT: it works fine if I use fileO = fopen(version, "w"); bypassing the strcpy and strcat calls. (haha, I said catcalls...)

So I have a CUDA program that I harvested some file I/O from the sequential version of the same program (non-CUDA).  The exact same code works with regular gcc compiles, but not through nvcc.  I know nvcc shunts C/C++ off to the native C++ compiler, but for some reason it's just not opening a writable file. I have opened and closed another file stream for reading in data in the code above this, but I do that in my sequential version of this and it works fine there.

Here's the relevant code:

```
else 
{
    char* version = "matrixExpCUDAx";
    char* filename = (char *)malloc(strlen(version) + strlen(argv[3]));

    strcpy(filename, version);
    strcat(filename, argv[3]);

    FILE *fileO;
    fileO = fopen(filename, "w");   

    if(DEBUG)
    {
        for (i=0; i<(dim*dim); i++) fprintf(stderr, "%f\n", h_O[i]);
    }
    else
    {
        if(fileO != NULL)
        {
            for (i=0; i<(dim*dim); i++)
            {
                fprintf(fileO, "%f\n", h_O[i]);
            }
            fclose(fileO);
        }
        else fprintf(stderr, "Write file failed to create\n");
    }
}
....
```

I get "Write file failed to create" everytime.

Any ideas?

Comment: Note the failed code formatting near the top; can you fix that up? (others can also fix it, but if several people try to edit the post at the same time, it'll be annoying for someone..)

Comment: Also note that `nvcc` is not a compiler and it did not compile this code, your standard host C++ compiler (`gcc` by the looks of the tags) did. Despite outward appearances, this question has nothing to do with CUDA or the CUDA toolchain, and everything to do with not understanding about string termination in C.

Comment: @talonmies : Thanks, yes.  I noted that nvcc uses the system C compiler in the original post.  I don't think it's string termination, since it works without the CUDA specific portions of the code and gcc as the compiler.  I'll look at it though, just in case.

Answer (score 1):

```
char* filename = (char *)malloc(strlen(version) + strlen(argv[3]));
```

First, you shouldn't have to cast the return value from `malloc(3)`. If you add `#include <stdlib.h>` to your program, you'll get the `malloc(3)` prototype that tells the compiler how to properly handle the return value from `malloc(3)`. Casting it yourself can paper over helpful warnings or errors that can catch bugs. Add the `#include` and remove the cast.

Also, this doesn't appear to allocate sufficient memory for your filename; don't forget that `strlen(3)` does *not* include space for the terminating ASCII `NUL` byte at the end of the string, but your `filename` will definitely need that terminating `NUL`.

Whenever you see some code like this:

```
bar = malloc(strlen(foo));
```

it is almost always a bug. It should instead look like this:

```
bar = malloc(strlen(foo)+1);
```

Even if the size calculation is broken out elsewhere, I often like to put the `+1` inside the `malloc()` call specifically, just to make sure I know it is there in the future.

When your `file0` is `NULL`, you should probably also call `perror(3)` to tell you *why* you weren't able to open the file. It might be "permission denied". It might be that the current working directory does not exist any more. (This will prevent you from creating files in the directory, even if your filesystem permissions would otherwise allow you to create files.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer sarnold.  I'm including stdlib.h at the top, but when I compile I get an error: "a value of type 'void *' cannot be used to initialize an entity of type 'char *'". I know gcc auto-links stdlib, but is it possible I might need to tell nvcc to do so?  That doesn't seem right to me based on my understanding of how nvcc calls gcc...  As for the length issue, I'm fairly sure I'm getting the nul term since I'm starting with a char* variable version before I process it into the filename. I _think_ the strlen(version) part of the malloc gets it. I did try the +1, but no change.

Comment: Oh, and perror() returns "No such file or directory" when I compile while casting malloc() to a char*.

Comment: Your top-most edit explains the `malloc(3)` casting. I'll have to accept that I'll never understand C++ -- it's just too different for me. I'm not sure why you're still getting "no such file or directory" -- can you print the filename and make sure it still makes sense?